# How to set last index values as first while drawing the CPBarPlot?

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I want to load the CPBarPlot with Last 10 index values when the reload data is called, is any function there to achieve like this....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you to determine the data to be plotted. Just return **10** in `-numberOfRecordsForPlot:` and figure out the amount to offset the index in `-numberForPlot:field:recordIndex:`. For instance, if your data set has 50 points and Core Plot asks for the data at index 5, return the point at index 50 - 10 + 5 = **45**.

Comment: hi can u send me some sample code for achieve my task, bcos i have tried lot didnt able to get it exactly......